# What causes this delay in a grid-template-rows transition?

Tags: css, css-grid

Ever since i found out that there's the option to animate `height: auto;` by using `grid-template-rows`, i have been using it wherever i see fit, like a menu or FAQ items.

Recently i noticed that the inner element does not slide as fast as the outer element does.

See this fiddle: https://codepen.io/stenpelzer/pen/bGOPrLX.

Why does this happen?

Edit: I found a [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77307807/3611289), but it does not answer the why. Please let me know if you have more information.

Comment: Firefox seems to work fine. Chrome and Safari don't.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally found a solution for this problem:

You define the `align-items` rule on the `.outer` element.
Example: https://codepen.io/Blackxes/pen/BaMKrxO

Dynamic units seem to cause this issue (em, fr, etc.) except `%` which just jumps to its size
while the `.inner` grows through the transition.

I assume the `fr` without `align-items` on the children doesn't "know" its children's size and calculates the `.inner` height incorrectly based on .. "something" which results in this odd behaviour.
As soon as you set `align-items` to something except none it works beautifully.

Comment: Wow! That's eh.. interesting. I agree with your assumption, it feels as though the inner element doesn't know where to put its contents.

Answer (score 0):

Add inside `.outer`   `transition-timing-function: linear;` The default is `ease`. This value sets the animation to a slow start then after a time period the speed increases and before it ends the speed again becomes slow.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. It didn't fully fix the issue, as it seems that the `ease` is on the `.inner`. Adding it there does not seem to help any bit either - which makes sense because there is no transition on `.inner`.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to fix the issue, though it doesn't feel very solid.

Adding `overflow: hidden;` to `.outer` and setting `height: 100000%` on `.inner` will make the inner element always be the height of the outer.

https://codepen.io/stenpelzer/pen/ExGBbKB